# running a web application on GCE instance re

Tags: python, flask, debian, virtualenv, google-compute-engine

Following [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) tutorial, I'm learning how to create a RESTful python service using `virtualenv` and `flask`

I've created a small `hello world` web application and executed it: `./app.py`.
This resulted in:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
```

But when I open the browser and enter `http://<external ip>:5000`, instead of seeing *hello world* I get:

> could not connect to <external ip>:5000

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `http://:5000` a typo? If not, try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. Another good tutorial if you are new to Flask: [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Comment: @Seberius yep its a typo, Thanks, my web application is running on a GCE so trying to call it from my macbook i replace 127.0.0.1 with the external ip of the GCE instance

Comment: Ok, this a deployment, which makes sense based on the title. I do not have experience with GCE unfortunately. You may wish to update the question to include your app's configuration to help others solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is clearly stated by this message:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

The server is listening on the `localhost` address only, so it will not see connections from other machines. If you want to make the server listen on the public interface you need to change the `app.run()` line as follows:

```
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

Comment: once I'm in production what is the proper way to configure the service?

Comment: In a production box you don't want to use Flask's own web server, you need to use a more robust server like nginx or apache. Flask has information on configuring these and other web servers for production.

Comment: just figured out that you are the author of the tutorial I'm following, great tutorial, Thank you!!!